# math formula format doesn't appear in android mathView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tinymce-4, wiris

I am trying to show math formula in my android app I use tiny_mce with WIRIS plugin to write formula as image below
[image]

the editor store the formula in the database as the following format

```
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mroot><mrow><mn>3</mn>
   <mi>x</mi></mrow><mn>2</mn></mroot><mo>&#215;</mo><mn>2</mn>
   <mimathvariant="normal">&#960;</mi></math></p>
```

I also use MathView in my android app to show this formula as following

```
 MathView testMathView=(MathView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    testMathView.setText("<p><math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">" +
          "<mroot><mrow><mn>3</mn><mi>x</mi></mrow><mn>2</mn></mroot>" +
          "<mo>&#215;</mo><mn>2</mn><mi mathvariant=\"normal\">&#960;</mi></math></p>");
```

but it doesn't work it shows me the only numbers without mathematics formula symbols

here are a GitHub library and tutorial for MathView which doesn't work with outputs of wiris editor 
[MathView on github](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView)

could you please give any help or suggestions to show wiris output format in android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read in docs on GitHub, which you linked, you should set `auto:engine="MathJax"` in `MathView` and `setText` as below:

```
testMathView.setText("$$<p><math xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML\">" +
      "<mroot><mrow><mn>3</mn><mi>x</mi></mrow><mn>2</mn></mroot>" +
      "<mo>&#215;</mo><mn>2</mn><mi mathvariant=\"normal\">&#960;</mi></math></p>$$");
```

Hope that this will work.